What is this valve coming out of the ground?
We just bought home, ~100 years old. First time home owners. I was mulling around the back yard and noticed this valve coming out of the ground, I have no idea what it is. The valve is located right next to the house. It wasn't called out in the inspection and honestly I'm a little worried to turn the valve to see what happens...should I? Do you have any recommendations on how to figure out what it is?
https://imgur.com/jCcwKSt
https://imgur.com/9LJs70I
https://imgur.com/q51V5KV
https://imgur.com/B6TKKcT
I' thinking about hiring a plumber and paying him to just stand next to me when i turn it in case something goes wrong. Is that crazy? Like what if I turn it and the valve breaks and water (or something else) shoots out? This is how paranoid I am.
If I were to hire a plumber, how would I frame the request to them? Help me figure out what this valve does , stand next to me when I turn it, be prepared to do something if it breaks? etc etc.


what state/country are you in? are there nearby water features (sprinklers, fountains, etc)?

Hey thank you for responding! I am i california USA. There is a waste line clean out maybe 5 feet from this location and there are water pipes that I think go into the house. I'm not so sure how the water actually gets into the house, I know in the 50s the city had a water line in the back but in the 2000s they moved it to the front. I will call the water dept today.

not confident, but https://www.westernwaterca.gov/392/How-to-turn-off-your-water says CA water shut off is outside. Do you know where your water shut off is (or could this be it)?

Welcome to home ownership! We can't say for certain what this valve might control but we can give suggestions as to how you might find out for yourself. You're wise to figure out now, while there's no emergency at hand, the locations of water valves and verify that they're functional. When plumbing goes wrong, running water can cause expensive damages if not shut off promptly.
The valve is shallow. You could dig a few feet to either side of it to discover what kind of pipe is connected and in what direction it leads. The valve handle is fairly buried in soil anyway so this would also be a good opportunity to clear that out. It'll also allow you to grip the handle well and find out whether the valve turns readily, and to see whether it begins leaking when operated. (Don't worry, if you're using reasonable hand force only and not a big wrench, you won't cause it to fail so catastrophically as to require immediate attention from a plumber.)
Have a look at whatever plumbing is visible inside the house in the basement or crawlspace. Can you identify any pipes inside the house that are near this valve and might lead to it? Given your understanding that water supply into the house now comes from the front, can you identify any pipes that exit the house underground toward the front? Any valves in such pipes?
There's virtually always a valve alongside a water meter. See if you can find your meter - they're often under a lid in the yard, but are sometimes inside the building. The pipe leading up to the meter is usually a responsibility of the water provider while the pipe following after the meter is almost always responsibility of the property owner. If the meter is in the yard there'll usually be a main shutoff valve inside the house too.
